# How do I make the hands follow the camera in my 3d FPS game?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, basically I had the arms and head as a child of the camera but now I added some animations to my character and I have to use them in their initial position so the animation will work (I made the script for looking around and that is why I had them as a child of the camera). That means I have to find a different method for the hands to follow the camera. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code. Basically what you want is to set a Vector3 to hand offset, and set a gameObject to the camera, and calculate from there:

```
Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, 0, 0.3);
GameObject cam;
void Update(){
 transform.position = cam.transform.position + offset;
}
```

Since your question wasn’t clear, and that might not have been what you wanted, you could use a parent game object, and set the camera as a child of it, and set the rest of the objects as child of that parent game object. Also make sure your player script should be in the parent game object.

Edit:

Make a parent game object, and name it “Player Rig”. Then out the camera underneath it in the hierarchy, and same for the hands. Place the hands where you want them to be. Then instead of having your scripts on the camera, put it on the Player Rig. Change the looking portion of your controller script to this:

```
void Update(){
 float X = Input.GetAxis(“Mouse X) * rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
 float Y = Input.GetAxis(“Mouse Y) * rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
 Y = Mathf.Clamp(Y, -89.5f, 89.5f);
 cam.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Y, 0f, 0f);
 arms.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Y, 0f, 0f);
 transform.rotation = Quaternion(0f, X, 0f);
}
```

Comment: and do i add the script on the both hands? I cannot create any parents in the rig cause it will mess up my animation, and to be more specific, the problem is when I look up or down with the arms, cause when i look left and right they follow the position of the body

Comment: Wait a minute, I am coming up with an answer and will edit my original post when I do. And answer this question: do you mean you want the arms to follow the y rotation of the camera?

Comment: Let me restate that: be clearer with your question. I don’t understand what the problem is, but this is what I understand: you do not have exactly what you want and there is a bug with the arms.

Comment: So, I want something like CSGO has for example, the player arms will always be following the camera (and you always see them in the "same" position when playing , even if you are facing different angles). In my case, the horizontal movement doesn't have a problem because the arms are moving with the body (and the body moves when I look around HORIZONTALLY). The problem is with the vertical look, as the body doesn't change its position when looking up or down. I used to child the arms to the camera (and it worked) but know I have this problem with the animation and i need to keep all as it is

Comment: Wait... so what are you using right now. The parent of camera and hands, or the script I wrote?

Comment: And i cant create parent inside the bones hoerarchy cause it will mess up the animation. Maybe you know how to apply the animation and keep the hands attavhed to camera but I thought it will be simpler to write a script

Comment: Give me a minute, I’ll try.

Comment: So know i use the parent camera and child hands and the animation wont play

Comment: If that doesn’t work, then I don’t know what you want.